# Alexa Skill Development: How to trigger a Routine

Tags: android, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to develop an Alexa skill and have been researching and looking into the skill development process. I have not been able to get a concrete answer. Can you trigger a routine from a skill? For example, I have stored an array list of routine names that I have gathered through an android app. The routine names could then be toggled on and off through app and the developed skill. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You currently can not, to my knowledge, call a routine from a skill. You can however call a skill from a routine.

For most of the features for Alexa you can think about a separation of personal device things that a end user can set like routines and a much smaller subset of items a skill developer can ask permission for. For example as a skill developer you can go to the permissions list in the developer console and see things like permissions for email, phone number, location, etc.

For a skill to call a routine there is a grey area of things that the user may be giving permission to that may be unintended. The Alexa team seems to have been very purposeful when even allowing a developer to ask for permissions.

Here is a blog post about the ability to call skills from routines.
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2019/10/tell-your-customers-they-can-now-invoke-your-skill-from-routines

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a routine from an alexa using IFTTT mkzense and and IFTTT webhooks.

1. Install the IFTTT Trigger skill on alexa and connect to your account
2. Create an account on mkzense and choose the free plan
3. Create an applet on IFTTT and choose the trigger as IFTTT webhook and action as mkzense trigger.
4. Create a routine on alexa and set the trigger as IFTTT Trigger and choose your actions
5. Finally, check the IFTTT webhooks documentation to retrieve your trigger URL and you can invoke the routine by making an HTTP request to that URL from your skill...